# Proper way of inputting values from text file

Tags: python, txt

I am having hard time to understand how to properly inert values into my variables from txt file. First line is number of test cases, then goes number of houses and then house binary string. Here are my input values:

```
2 (Number of tests [INT])
3 (Number of houses [INT])
111 (Binary string [String])
6 (Number of houses [INT])
100100 (Binary string [String])
```

I know we can do like this:

```
test_cases = int(input())
for i in range(test_cases):
  house_number = int(input())
  house_string = input()
  some_function(int value1, string value2)
```

But I want to create txt file so I will not type these values every time. I know how to open and read txt file. However can not imagine how can I pass variables.

```
with open('test.txt') as file:
  lines = file.readlines()

  for line in lines:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your text file is consistent with formatting you can loop over every two elements and turn them into a list of tuples. Note that this code excludes the first element assuming there are complete pairs:

```
with open('test.txt') as file:
    output_lst = []
    lines = file.readlines()
    for i,k in zip(lines[1::2], lines[2::2]):
        output_lst.append((int(i), str(k)))
```